# append two variable by giving four spaces in between them

Tags: shell, scripting

I have two variables and I have to append the value of both variable into a 3rd variable by giving 4 spaces in between the variable.

for eg:

```
$ a="a"
$ b="b"
$ echo $a"     "$b
```

output:

```
a    b
```

when I am doing

```
$ c=$(echo $a"    "$b)
$ echo $c
```

output:

```
a b
```

Required output:

```
a    b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just say:

```
c="$a    $b"
```

This will set `$c` as `$a` + 4 spaces + `$b`.

To see it working, use `echo` or `printf` **using double quotes so that the format is kept**:

```
$ c="$a    $b"
$ echo "$c"
a    b
```

Note, also, that when you say:

```
$ c=$($a"    "$b)
```

You will get the error:

> bash: a    b: command not found

Because you are using `var=$(command)` syntax, which stores in `$var` the output of the command `command`. However, the command you are trying to run is `$a"    "$b`, that is, `a    b`, which is not a command.

Comment: thanks for the reply,  `a="a"
 b="b"
 c="$a   $b"
 echo $c` is also not working, sorry I didn't type my question correctly, edited it

Comment: you have to say `echo "$c"` to preserve the spaces.